# Create Shortcut based on an AD HomeDirectory

Tags: powershell

I'm Trying to create a script to create shortcuts for students based on their AD HomeDirectory and naming the Link as there AD display name. Homedirectory is a UNC path.

However when i get to the $shortcut.targetpath area it complains about invalid parameter.  I think it's not liking the data in the $homedir variable.  My code is noobish.  But i'm still learning.  Any help would be great.

```
    ###Read a Sisweb Extract
    $data=Get-Content C:\studentfile.txt

    ###For each row in the file execute all of this
    foreach ($line in $data)
    {

        ###Parse the row and retrieve SSID
        $columns = $line -split '\t'
        $studentid = $columns[3]

        ###If a SSID is found execute the following code.
        if($studentid -match "[0-9]")
        {
            ###Retrieve DisplayName of the SSID.
            $displayname=Get-aduser $studentid -property displayname |ft displayname -hidetableheaders |out-string

            ###Retrieve Home Directory of the SSID
            $homedir=Get-aduser $studentid -property homedirectory |ft homedirectory -hidetableheaders |out-string

            ###Parse the homedirectory data and retrieve the servername.
            $pathdata="$homedir" -split '\\'
            $server=$pathdata[2]


            ###Create Shortcut
            $WshShell=New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
            $Shortcut=$WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\temp\$displayname.lnk")
            $Shortcut.TargetPath="$homedir"
            $Shortcut.Save()

        }
   }
```

Comment: One issue you might have is the output stored in `$homedir`. When i run that code again my own org i get extra lines. Something like this might be better `Get-aduser $studentid -property homedirectory | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty homedirectory`. You need to use -`first 1` since you are returning an object that could potentially have more than one user and we only want one return value.

Comment: Matt, thanks.  That cleaned up my data and i was able to create the shortcut.  Still don't understand what -first 1 does but i will research it.  You were right the culprit was the extra lines. Thanks!

Comment: If you had search for several users ex. `Get-Aduser -Filter {department -eq "Sanitation Engineering"}` This would return an object with all users. If you only wanted one you could pipe the results into `Select-Object -First 1` and it would only output the first user. [Tech net](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) definition says "Specifies the number of objects to select from the beginning of an array of input objects."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to build an answer since i see a couple of things that should be addressed. Ultimately I think your issue lies with your assignment of `$homedir`.

`if($studentid -match "[0-9]")` This code will check to see if `$studentid` contains a single numerical digit. Was this on purpose? Currently you would get a hit if an ID was `sdfhgkjhg3kjg` since that contains one digit. A simple addition would be to change it to `if($studentid -match "^[0-9]{6}$")` for example. Means that it will match a single line that contained exactly 6 digits.

`$displayname=Get-aduser $studentid -property displayname |ft displayname -hidetableheaders |out-string` I see this twice. I would update this since the Format-Table doesnt really serve a purpose and you can use `Select-Object` to accomplish your goal.

```
Get-aduser $studentid -property displayname | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty displayname 
Get-aduser $studentid -property homedirectory | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty homedirectory
```

**OR**

Instead of call `get-aduser` twice you could combine both your variable assignments.

```
$singleStudent = Get-aduser $studentid -property homedirectory,displayname
$displayname = $singleStudent.DisplayName
$homedir = $singleStudent.HomeDirectory
```

Comment: your way of calling get-aduser is a lot cleaner.  I will use that.  The student id read file if statement was the only way i knew how at the time to parse my extract file.  I will give your other way a shot.  I'm still learning all this stuff, but powershell is becoming my best friend.

Comment: "powershell is becoming my best friend" Thats what my profile says!